# android sensor processing librares

Tags: android, sensors

When I use accelerometer in my Android app, sometimes I have to low pass filter it; when I use compass, I have to do some calculations to find the azimuth; etcetera, etcetera. Does anyone know a good android library that would make it easy to use sensors, without coding such calculations by myself?

Answer (score 0):

There is library a guy mentioned in DroidCon. Its called SensorFusion.
Haven't been able to locate the exact library , but here is a nice article briefing on what needs to be done to improve the readings recieved from various sensors.
http://www.thousand-thoughts.com/2012/03/android-sensor-fusion-tutorial/